# Which CPAN module would you recommend for turning HTML into plain text?

Tags: perl, cpan, lynx

Which CPAN module would you recommend for turning HTML into formatted plain text?

One strict requirement is that the module must handle Unicode characters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I like [HTML::FormatText](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML::FormatText) and [HTML::FormatText::WithLinks](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML::FormatText::WithLinks)

Answer (score 4):

See the example script [htext](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/GAAS/HTML-Parser-3.64/eg/htext) that comes with [HTML::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML::Parser).