# How can I render HTML as text using Perl as Lynx does?

Tags: html, perl, render

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which CPAN module would you recommend for turning HTML into plain text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934638/which-cpan-module-would-you-recommend-for-turning-html-into-plain-text)

#### Question:

- Is there a module to **render HTML**, specifically to gather the text, while adhering to **font-style tags**, such as `<tt>`, `<b>`, `<i>`, etc and **break-line** `<br>`, similar to [Lynx](http://lynx.isc.org/).

**For example**:

`# cat test.html`

```
<body>  
<div id="foo" class="blah">  
<tt>test<br>
<b>test</b><br>
whatever<br>
test</tt>
</div>
</body>
```

`# lynx.exe --dump test.html`

```
test
test
whatever
test
```

**Note:** the second line should be bold.

Comment: Don't miss: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934638/which-cpan-module-would-you-recommend-for-turning-html-into-plain-text

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Lynx is a big program and its html rendering will be non trivial.

How about this:

```
my $lynx = '/path/to/lynx';
my $html = [ html here ];
my $txt = `$lynx --dump --width 9999 -stdin <<EOF\n$html\nEOF\n`;
```

Comment: +1. Wanted to suggest the same answer.

Comment: This might just have to do, unfortunately.

Comment: Shouldn't line 3 contain $lynx insteady of lynx?  Otherwise, /path/to/lynx is ignored.

Answer (score 6):

Go to [search.cpan.org](http://search.cpan.org) and search for [HTML text](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=HTML%20text&mode=all) which will give you lots of options to suit your particular needs.  [HTML::FormatText](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML::FormatText) is a good baseline, and then branch out into specific variations of it, for example [HTML::FormatText::WithLinks](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML::FormatText::WithLinks) if you want to preserve links as footnotes.

Answer (score 2):

I am on Windows so I cannot fully test this but you can adapt [htext](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/GAAS/HTML-Parser-3.64/eg/htext) that comes with [HTML::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML::Parser):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

use HTML::Parser;
use Term::ANSIColor;

use HTML::Parser 3.00 ();

my %inside;

sub tag {
   my($tag, $num) = @_;
   $inside{$tag} += $num;
   print " ";  # not for all tags
}

sub text {
    return if $inside{script} || $inside{style};
    my $esc = 1;
    if ( $inside{b} or $inside{strong} ) {
        print color 'blue';
    }
    elsif ( $inside{i} or $inside{em} ) {
        print color 'yellow';
    }
    else {
        $esc = 0;
    }
    print $_[0];
    print color 'reset' if $esc;
}

HTML::Parser->new(api_version => 3,
    handlers => [
        start => [\&tag, "tagname, '+1'"],
        end   => [\&tag, "tagname, '-1'"],
        text  => [\&text, "dtext"],
    ],
    marked_sections => 1,
)->parse_file(shift) || die "Can't open file: $!\n";;
```